# Is LA a prereq for AA?

Tags: soft-question

I just finished an elementary number theory book and I'm wondering if I can start abstract algebra right away or do I have to learn some linear algebra first ?

Comment: If the linear algebra course involves doing formal proofs, that might be good practice for abstract algebra, but i wouldn't say (according to courses I took or according to courses at my university) that linear algebra is a prerequisite for abstract algebra.

Comment: I supposed number theory would have had lots of proofs. Also assume you're a pretty good math student. To be sure about prereq, why not ask the abstract algebra instructor?

Comment: No instructor, I'm learning it all from books. I think I can learn any necessary linear algebra on the way, thanks!

Comment: Then you should be asking which abstract algebra books are good for self-study. I would want one with at least 1/3 of the problems answered or 'hinted' in the back of the book.

Comment: I'm using "A Book of Abstract Algebra", I heard it's very good for self-study.

Comment: I am not sure about the book you mention but there should be examples and problems in the first few chapters involving the multiplication of invertible square matrices. Though it is something you should be able to pick up as you go along, or you can always stop and study some linear algebra first. I took linear alg, abstract alg, intro to abstract math, and calc 3 in the same semester. So I wouldn't be too concerned, although having an instructor is helpful. I actually found some of my abstract algebra knowledge coming in handy at times in linear algebra, and vice versa.

Comment: Alright, thanks!

Comment: If abstract algebra includes Field Theory, you'll need some Linear Algebra.